# Live Search with AJAX Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, search

I'm following the railscasts rails ajax tutorial and geting into some trouble. Everything went well, except the live keyup. The live search does not work, I have to click the search button to get the result.

Here is my application.js

```
$("#emos_search input").keyup(function() {
$.get($("#emos_search").attr("action"), $("#emos_search").serialize(), null, "script");
return false;
});
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag emoticons_path, :method => 'get', :id => "emos_search" do %>
  <p>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
  <div id="emos"><%= render 'emos' %></div>
<% end %>
```

emoticons_controller.rb

```
def index
  @emoticons = Emoticon.search params[:search] 
end
```

emoticon.rb

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    where('name LIKE ? or emo LIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%") 
  else
    scoped
  end
 end
```

I don't know what is the problem. I think I already followed the steps in tutorial. And there is nothing showed in js console.

Comment: the parameters are `jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )` why you set success function to null ?

Comment: now I know what the problem is. it is not about search function at all. 
what I did is actually right, but somehow the application.js is not called :/
what I did to solved the problem is copied the application.js in public and called it from layout/application.html
I am not really sure what is the reason behind it, but it works now.
maybe you or anyone else know what is the reason?
thank you